How can I enforce my type to throw an error when some property desn't belong to a return type
enum ScopeType {
    LIST = "LIST",
    GENERIC = "GENERIC"
}

type Generic<T> = T

type List<T> = T & {
    limit: number;
};

interface GetApiPropsGeneric<T> {
    props: (storeState: string) => Generic<T>
    api: (args: Generic<T>) => void
    type: string
    scope: ScopeType.GENERIC
}


interface GetApiPropsList<T> {
    props: (storeState: string) =>  List<T>
    api: (args: List<T>) => void
    type: string
    scope: ScopeType.LIST
}

type NewT = {
    test: string,
}

const apiProps = <T extends unknown>(a: GetApiPropsList<T> | GetApiPropsGeneric<T>) => {
    console.log("as")
}

apiProps<NewT>({
    scope: ScopeType.LIST,
    props: (_) => ({
        test: "1444",
        limit:12,
        abc:"abc"
    }),
    api: () => {},
    type: "asd"
})

The property "abc" does not exist at the return type of props but TS doesn't throw an error.
I am expecting that return type of props is a function that returns an object with only test and limit. And any key added should return an error

In general you cannot achieve this; excess properties are not considered type errors, see this q/a. There are various tricks to discourage excess properties but none that I know of can be used transparently with your code as-is; you can switch to use generics, requiring currying, as shown here, but that's really complicated and fights against TS's type system for little benefit. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

TypeScript only enforces properties that have to be there, but it does not enforce the absence of properties. This is because it is based on JavaScript, which is typeless and allows any property to exist anywhere.
